# "I'm not welcome" or "I'm not welcomed"?

Tags: difference, transatlantic-differences

When I read an example sentence in Danish *Jeg er ikke velkommen* that means **I'm not welcome**, I confused whether people actually use this phrase. Then I tried to ask a question in the other site and they answered that it's more common to say **I'm not welcomed** rather than the previous one. At least in English, which I'm interested in focusing on. I.e. the difference between:

> - I'm not welcomed ...
> - I'm not welcome ...

I'm aware that *welcome* is an adjective in the second sentence but a verb in the first. However, I assume that I can possibly use both interchangeably? For instance, in this sentence below:

> I'm not ... in this house. Sorry, I'm leaving!

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why anyone should tell you that _I'm not welcomed_ is more common.

Comment: Something might not be welcomed, and very likely, not welcome either. Unwanted phone calls for example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As has been mentioned, **not welcome** is the more common expression. But **not welcomed** isn't merely a less common variant but has a narrower meaning. I can say "I am not welcome there" without ever having been to the place in question, simply understanding that I would not receive a welcome if I did go. On the other hand, for me to say "I am not welcomed there" requires that I have been to the place in question and not received a welcome.

Comment: For me, criticism of my hairstyle is not welcome; your criticism of my hairstyle was not welcomed by my mother.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Exactly. Your first statement does not require that anyone ever has criticised your hairstyle (or indeed ever will), but your second statement refers to a concrete instance where someone did.

Comment: So we can't say "your criticism will not be welcomed by my mother" or "your criticism will be not welcomed by my mother"?

Comment: @justhalf You can say that (at least the first version – the second version is not in a natural English order). You are making a statement about a potential future event if it were to happen. But "was not welcomed" is in the past tense, so for that statement to be correct someone needs to have made the criticism and your mother needs to have rejected it.

Comment: Ah thanks. My confusion is because in relation to your answer, which distinguish between ever actually going there and not. With the "will not be welcomed" since it's the future, then you have never been to the place in question, right?

Comment: @justhalf To make it clearer, you might say that there is an implied unwritten qualifier in your first statement such as "Your criticism of my hair will not *likely* be welcomed by my mom" or "*I'm guessing that* your criticism of my hair will not be welcomed by my mom" as your first version suggests a future event that you are speculating about.

Comment: @JonSG When it comes to a mother and her son I think we're on safe ground leaving   the statement unqualified. ;-)

Comment: The phrase "I am not welcomed there" sounds stranger than "I was not welcomed there", though.  The use of the present "am" over the past "was" makes it sounds like you make a habit of going to a place where, as a rule, you are never welcomed.

Comment: If it took place in the past, it should be "I wasn't welcomed".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You are right, the use of 'am' does indicate an ongoing practice. And I think it's unfortunately not uncommon to be in the habit of going somewhere but never being welcomed in the way that you thought you might be. But to say that you were "not welcome" there would be stating too much, as that would suggest an active opposition to your presence.

Answer (score 5):

**Not welcome** is the usual expression, regardless of the person concerned.
**Not welcomed** is also correct, just unusual, as the Google Books Ngram Viewer link below indicates. There is no difference in meaning.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am+not+welcome%2Cam+not+welcomed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20not%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20not%20welcomed%3B%2Cc0

Comment: No, the meaning is not identical; see for example [Hamish Lawson's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/309127/11296).

Comment: @psmears While criticism is not always welcome/welcomed, it can be enlightening.

Comment: Be very careful treating ngram graph comparisons as evidence of presence/absence of usage! Exhibit A: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am+happy%2Cam+sad&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20happy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20sad%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

The simple present usually indicates a recurring or habitual event or action, and is not common in English. "I am not welcomed" is the passive voice of this, indicating that someone, or people, are either in the exact moment of not welcoming you, or habitually don't welcome you. In the example you give, you're giving a reason for leaving at this moment, so the habitual sense doesn't work, so this phrase makes sense only if said at the moment that a welcome would be expected, and even then would be awkward phrasing.